# remove cell from comboBox on click javafx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, cell

I have the following action when clicking on a cell of a Combobox in javafx.
Now i want the cell to be removed from the Combobox when it was clicked. How can I do that? Is there any way to remove a cell?

```
 notificationCombo.setCellFactory(lv -> {
        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? null : item);
            }
        };
        cell.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                for(Product product:products){
                    if(cell.getText().equals(product.getName())){
                        selectedLoadProduct = product;
                        loadProduct(selectedLoadProduct);
                        updateProd(selectedLoadProduct,false);
                        initGui();
                        selectedLoadProduct = null;
                        createProductSelection();
            }}}
        });
        return cell ;
    });
```

Comment: notificationCombo is the Combobox

Comment: You shouldn't deal modify the location in the scene of a cell used by a virtualized container yourself. Use the appropriate property of the control. But why are you using a `cellFactory` here? Wouldn't it be sufficient to listen to changes of the `value` property?